# How to use Matplotlib, Terminal, and Sublime Text (text editor) together

Tags: matplotlib, plot, terminal, sublimetext2, graphing

On Sublime Text, I have the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def do_dumb_plot():

    x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

I want to have this plot show using Terminal. I tried stuff like:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

>>> python mygraph.py
```

But nothing really works.
Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have a python script with a function in it and you want
to start it from the command line so that the function is executed?

You could add this lines at the bottom of your file:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    do_dumb_plot()
```

That would cause the function you defined to be executed if the script is directly called 
by python mygraph.py but not if it is imported by another script.

You could start python in interactive mode:

```
python -i mygraph.py
```

and then:

```
>>>do_dumb_plot()
```

If you're using ipython you could do:

```
[1] %run mygraph.py

[2] do_dumb_plot()
```